# Is there a sequence of $ C^\infty $ compactly supported functions limiting to $ f(x)$=1

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Is there a sequence $\left(g_m\right)_{m\geqslant 1}$ of compactly supported $C^{\infty}$ functions converging to $ f(x)=1$ uniformly with the condition that there is no compact $K \subset \mathbb R$ such that
>   $\operatorname{card}\left\{ m: \operatorname{supp}(g_m)\cap K \ne \emptyset\right\} = \infty$?

Comment: What is cond and what is $g_m$?

Comment: the number of elements of  a set,here the number of such indices m .   
   and     g_{m} is m-th element of the sequence

Comment: What kind of limit do you mean? Pointwise convergence, uniform convergence...?

Comment: uniform convergence

Comment: there was a mistake in the last line,

Comment: @ Wojowu : is your conclusion still true?

Comment: Actually, I seem to have misread the question before. My answer didn't answer your pre-edit question, but it actually answers this question of yours after the edit. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: A compact subset of $\mathbb R$ is bounded so if $supp(g_n)$ is compact then $\sup_x|g_n(x)-1|\geq 1$  so convergence to $1$ cannot be uniform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function even with pointwise convergence.

Hint: choose $K=\{0\}$ (a finite, hence clearly compact, set).